# Using schtasks in interactive mode

Tags: windows, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

How can I run `schtasks.exe` in interactive mode?
Like "at.... /interactive"?

I run it on Windows XP so there isn't the `/IT` option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/IT` option.

---

After you updated your question to state that you are using XP, it would appear that this option is not available on XP.

Comment: I can't use it in winXP..

Comment: Then use `at ... /interactive`.

Comment: That's the problem. I want to use schtasks, not at, but I want to use interactive. Isn't there option for that?

Comment: @erez Apparently not.